# Cocos2d and CocoaAsyncSocket

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cocoaasyncsocket

Please help me fix this problem :

1 - I create a Cocos2d project, add CFNetwork.framework.

2 - I add GCDAsyncUdpSocket.h and GCDAsyncUdpSocket.m from CocoaAsyncSocket library to my project

3 - Built.

---> I have 201 error????? .(although I dont do anything) . I just add GCDAsyncUdpSocket.h and GCDAsyncUdpSocket.m from CocoaAsyncSocket library and built. All errors occur in GCDAsyncUdpSocket.m .

But if  I change :

1 - I create a View base app project (not cocos2d project), add CFNetwork.framework.

2 - I add GCDAsyncUdpSocket.h and GCDAsyncUdpSocket.m from CocoaAsyncSocket library to my project

3 - Built.

--->>>It's ok, and I can use GCDAsyncUdpSocket .

How to add CocoaAsyncSocket library (GCDAsyncUdpSocket.h and GCDAsyncUdpSocket.m) for cocos2d project?

Please help me....

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are linking `CFNetwork.framework` with your Cocos2D project.

Another thing you have to fix is related to Cocos2D not supporting ARC (CocoaAsyncSocket is an ARC project, so you have a mismatch). Either you patch your project/Cocos2D base following what this [post](http://www.tinytimgames.com/2011/07/22/cocos2d-and-arc/) suggest or you install the [latest development brach of Cocos2D](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/tree/develop/cocos2d) (which should fix this).

Comment: I added CFNetwork.framework (both My project). Have many error for Cocos2D project (although I dont do anything) . I just add GCDAsyncUdpSocket.h and GCDAsyncUdpSocket.m from CocoaAsyncSocket library and built. All errors occur in GCDAsyncUdpSocket.m . But with View base app --> It's ok, and I can use GCDAsyncUdpSocket . Please help me. Thank you very much. – user1002290 6 mins ago

Comment: Thank you, I will try and reply for you. Thank you for your help.